# mac : zsh command not found: rustc

Tags: macos, rust, zshrc

I have installed rust on mac folllowing [this](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install), and then I updated .zshrc with:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH"
```

But in new terminal, `rustc --version` still gives:

```
zsh: command not found: rustc
```

What am I missing here?

PS: I had added the path somewhere in between existing paths. I moved it to last, and seems it did the trick. But not sure why.

Comment: The why is likely one of your "export PATH" commands sets it instead of appending to it (missing a $PATH in its components)

Comment: Have you sourced `.zshrc` after editing it? Or have you opened a new terminal?

Comment: @jmb, I actually tried both. With sourced, it worked first tme but stopped working after closing the terminal.

Comment: It may be worth trying shellcheck on your .zshrc, either install it or use the online version at https://www.shellcheck.net/